# How to solve "Module not found error" in Visual Studio Code and cmd

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to run a simply python script from Visual Studio Code or directly from cmd. When I run this script from cmd using "python removeFileTypes.py", it works perfectly. However, when I try to run the same script with cmd using "removeFileTypes.py", I get a module not found error. The same holds for when I try to run in it in PyCharm or Visual Studio Code.

What should I do to make it work in all cases?

The full Traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NewFolder\removeFileTypes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from path import Path
ImportError: No module named path
```

The file that I am trying to run

```
from path import Path

d = Path('D:/NewFolder/')

d.walkfiles('*')
list(d.walkfiles())

files = d.walkfiles('*es.srt')
for file in files:
    file.remove()
    print(file)
```

Comment: I suggest you make this a habit from the start when asking questions to anyone, post the full traceback of the error message, not just the one message from it. Helps a lot :)

Comment: you do know you need to type in python before running it.

Comment: @RandomChannel: that is not correct. You can also notice that from the error. Besides, it does not explain why it does not work from PyCharm or Visual Studio Code...exact same error.

Comment: ok, so try running a simple `print("hello")` script and tell me how it works, because if that works then its with your code, not with the python loader.

Comment: Running a simple script without imports works perfectly fine when just calling hello.py from cmd window.

Comment: let me ask the obvious here. Have you run `pip install path`? or on osx/linux `pip3 install path`?

Comment: cuz if you havent, it wont work

Comment: The answer to your question is already in my text. I can run the script, or any other script for that matter, smoothly without any problems when I call python first. However, it somehow does not work if I call just the script itself or try to run in Visual Studio Code or Pycharm.

Comment: I think my system somehow gets confused between python 2.7 and 3.7...Is that possible?